# Can I use Quartz Composer with iOS?

Tags: ios, quartz-composer

I wan't to draw a view which has several strings, these strings's text could be changed by my program code, how can I build my program with Quartz Composer? 
I want Quartz Composer define how my view looks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quartz Composer compositions are not supported at all on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Some people are trying to make this happen !!

Quartz Composer for iOS
http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2013/06/04/quartz-composer-for-ios/

I am also looking forward to it !